# Which SOLID Principles are violated? ( What should I do to solve this Controller issues? )

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

recently I've had a Job interview which The interviewer gave me a piece of code to solving it's violation of SOLID principles but I'm not an expert programmer and because of lack of knowledge couldn't find any issues,now I'm asking you to help me

what is wrong with this piece of code?

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
namespace InterviewTest.Controllers
{
    public class EMailController : Controller
    {
        const string logFile = "log.txt";

        // this is a method which takes an id or a username after searching in 
       //database this method sends an email to the searched id or username 
       //then this operation Is stored in a log file...

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password = myPassword;";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblUsers where id = " + int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]) + " or username = '" + Request.QueryString["username"] + "'" , con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();

            string email = reader.GetString(2);

            emailer.Instance.send(email);

            FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("c:\\myapp\\" + logFile);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

            sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " sent email to " + email);

            fs.Close();

            return View();
        }

        // This is a class Which is responsible for sending email
        public class emailer
        {
            private static emailer instance = null;

            public static emailer Instance
            {
                get {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new emailer();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }

            internal void send(string email) {
                try {
                    // Suppose this piece of code has been implemented
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is more than `one operation` happening in the method `public ActionResult Index()`.

Comment: Its worrying that you went for an interview as a developer and couldnt find a single thing wrong with this code :-s

Comment: SOLID doesn't cover basic security principals but holy SQL injection attack batman!

Answer (score 3):

(I'm assuming you know the principles by heart so I will not explain what they mean)

Single responsibility: because the controller takes care of retrieving data from a database (which is usually done through a repository or service-repository combo) as well as e-mail sending, which should be in a service which is used in the controller.

Open-closed principle: the email sender class is implemented in the same place as the controller so its clearly not open for extension and closed for modification

Interface segregation: not in use at all

Dependency inversion: not in use at all, e.g. the repository class and the email sending service should be hidden behind interfaces (i.e. IEmailSender, IMyDataRepository) and the controller should use those not knowing/caring about the exact implementation. Even better if used in conjunction with dependency injection -> the controller would get instances of classes implementing these interfaces in the constructor through usage Unity, SimpleInjector etc.

Liskov: There is no use of class hierarchy and interfaces etc.

If I had to implement something like this:

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{
  // Interface segregation applied
  private IEmailSendingService emailService;
  private IUserService userService;
  private ILoggingService loggingService

  // Dependency inversion principle / Dependency injection applied
  public EmailController(IEmailService mailSrvc, IUserservice usrSvc, ILoggingService log)
  {
      this.emailService = mailSrvc;
      this.userService = usrSvc;
      this.loggingService = log;
  }

  public ActionResult SendEmail()
  {
    try
    {
      var emailAddress = this.userService.GetEmail(...);
      // validate email address, maybe through another service
      if(Validator.ValidateEmail())
      {
          // Single responsibility applied
          this.emailService.SendEmail(emailAddress);
      }          
    }
    catch(MailNotFoundException ex)
    {
      this.loggingService.LogError("Email address not found for xy user");
      return NotFound();
    }
    catch(EmailSendingFailedException ex)
    {
      this.loggingService.LogError("Could not send email because xyz");
      // return internalservererror etc.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      this.loggingService.LogError("...");
    }          

      // return whats needed
  }
}
```

The example is not immacculate but you can get the gist of it :)